# TypeError: size; expecting a recognized type filling string dict

Tags: python, dictionary, size, typeerror

I have been working on Python script for Abaqus and it has to do with dynamic changes in the parameters of the model. The script opens up a **.txt file** and reads different values. The values are separated using tabs and I am using *split() function* of the Abaqus-Python to read the values properly once I have assigned them to a list.

The last index is [5] and it contains mesh size, again a float value. The structure is properly drawn in ABAQUS, the only error it throws me is while assigning the mesh size:

```
File "C:/Users/ANANT/PyCharmProjects/test_final/test_copy.py", line 104, in <module>
    beamPart.seedPart(deviationFactor=0.1, minSizeFactor=0.1, size=mesh)
TypeError: size; found 'module', expecting a recognized type filling string dict
```

So I tried using **repr()** to make it a string, but I was it will throw me that the input should be float/integer value and it did exactly the same. Now I am stuck and I can't work any further. I even tried to truncate the float value to 3-decimal points for the mesh size, but it would still throw the same error.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks a lot :)

[input file with truncated mesh size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWy2d.jpg)

Comment: This question is really hard to answer. First, most of the people here won't know Abaqus. Second, the question is not self-contained (Please do not provide any links, try to give as much information within your question). Third, you do not provide any code, were one could gather insights and figure out, where the error origins. Please refere to [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for further guidance.

Comment: This has nothing to do with ABAQUS, the error is python related with the error type as mentioned above. Moreover, the images I have attached contains whatever is required. Thank you for your concern.

Comment: You could easily copy the error text here, so whenever the link is broken, all the information required is still available. Same for the input. Just saying, this will improve the chance that somebody will answer the question.

Comment: beamPart.seedPart(deviationFactor=0.1, minSizeFactor=0.1, size=mesh)
TypeError: size; found 'module', expecting a recognized type filling string dict

So the error comes up **while assigning the float value to size = mesh**

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that `seedPart` expects a `size` argument that fulfills the requirement "a recognized type filling string dict". I don't know what this means, but the example [here](http://dsk.ippt.pan.pl/docs/abaqus/v6.13/books/gsa/default.htm?startat=ap01s05.html) is:

```
p.seedPart(size=2.0)
```

So you probably need a float. But `mesh` is a *module*. You probably have something like:

```
import mesh
```

Or:

```
import ... as mesh
```

in your code.

Try to print `mesh` before the line that raises the error.

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback, I just checked the same. It wants me to input a float variable there but also that it is a module being imported from the abaqus constants. So I switched the variable name and it worked. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

so, the 'size=mesh' parameter passed is apparently not of correct type. mesh is of type 'module'. is this intended?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I checked back and apparently, it is both a module and a variable, changing the name helped. Debugging a 580 line code, I totally neglected the fact that I have this double name problem.